# Big Commerce ReferenceError & InvalidStateError

Tags: jquery, bigcommerce

I am trying to debug why my expanding read-more isn't working on my big commerce site.

The page is:
http://snottynoses.com.au/vaporisers/

I have added the following script to the footer:

```
<script>
(function($) {
$('#show').click(function(e) {
    $('#cdscontainer').toggle();
$('#show').toggle();

});
$('#hide').click(function(e) {
    $('#cdscontainer').toggle();
$('#show').toggle();
});
})( jQuery );
 </script>
```

And the following to the css:

```
#cdscontainer {display:none;}
```

And the text on page is sitting inside this:

```
<a id="show" href="#cdscontainer">Read more…</a><div id="cdscontainer">
Paste text here…
<a id="hide" href="#cdscontainer">...Hide Content</a>
</div>
```

I don't think the script is loading properly as it doesn't work on the front end, however if i add the script using firebug or chrome's console tool, it works a treat.

If you open up your inspector tools, you can see there a number of console errors that might be causing this.

What on eath could be causing these errors and what might i do to fix them?

Thanks for any help/advice/suggestions :]

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to reinitialize jQuery twice. Modify your code to read:

```
<script>
$(function() {

  // Bind the click event handler to both elements:
  $('#show, #hide').click(function() {
    $('#cdscontainer').toggle();
    $('#show').toggle(); // Should this be here? It will hide all of the content.
  });

});
</script>
```